# What is the name of this list parts?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to make a side menu just like this.
I took a look at whole parts in Palette but couldn't find:(

What is the name of this list parts? How did they design this?

[image: List view]

Comment: it look like an ExpandableListView.

Comment: @HoanNguyen What about style??

Comment: I do not deal with style so I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

1 : You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884525/how-could-i-create-a-view-like-iphone-settings-in-android)

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want but this is quite helpfull.